# IAM policy deny AWS Aurora creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-iam, amazon-aurora

I have an IAM policy below to deny create RDS without enable MultiAZ, it's work fine when I create non-Aurora DB with multiAZ enabled. But when I create Aurora DB, I got explicit deny in an identity-based policy, as far as I know Aurora DB instance always have rds:MultiAz set to True, so it must be passed my policy.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Action": [
            "rds:CreateDBInstance",
            "rds:ModifyDBInstance"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "Bool": {
                "rds:MultiAz": "false"
            }
        }
    }
]}
```

is there something wrong or what might causing this issue?

Comment: I don't know, if I change rds:MultiAz" to "true", Aurora can be created, but non-aurora multiAZ enabled got deny issue with this policy, really weird.

Comment: what do you mean by "Aurora DB instance always have rds:MultiAz set to True"??

Comment: @Riz: I mean Aurora enable multi az by default

Comment: Doesn't it depend on what you select when you create  aurora db? I mean , if you select multiaz off while creating the aurora db, this should work right? I am confused about the "always true" part. Why aurora db has to be in multiaz, it can be in single az too.